# How to determine what dependency is forcing the scala version to be 2.10 when scalaVersion is set to 2.11.2

Tags: scala, sbt, securesocial

I'm trying to build the lunatech-securesocial-poc project with scala 2.11.2 and I've updated the scalaVersion in projects/Build.scala. This project depends on securesocial, which I've built locally with 2.11.2 and named its artifact version master-SNAPSHOT. I've updated the dependency in lunatech-securesocial-poc's project to use this version of securesocial. However, SBT (activator) fails to compile because it is looking for ws.securesocial#securesocial_2.10;master-SNAPSHOT.  How can I find out what is causing the scala version to be overridden to 2.10. I want 2.11.2. Obviously some dependency is forcing it, but I want to find out what that dependency is, and fix it.

I've tried adding:

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value

evictionWarningOptions := EvictionWarningOptions.default.withWarnTransitiveEvictions(true).withWarnDirectEvictions(true).withWarnScalaVersionEviction(true)
  ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }

to my Build.scala and I'm using SBT version 0.13.7.  I don't see why it is so hard for SBT to just abort and tell me that XXX dependency is preventing it from using 2.11.2 and requiring 2.10.

Anyone?

Comment: What does your `Build.scala` look like right now?

Comment: Here is my build.scala:

http://pastebin.com/07CJwkKr

Comment: Turned out it was a silly mistake in my Build.scala. While I defined scalaVersion in the object (ApplicationBuild) that extends Build, and used it  in some dependencies, I failed to include the setting of scalaVersion in the Project settings list.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`sbt-dependency-graph`](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin to find this out.

Comment: Thanks.

I tried adding this to my plugins.sbt file:

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.4")

and this to my Build.scala:

  net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

but when I enter:

  activator dependency-graph

I get:

[error] Not a valid command: dependency-graph (similar: dependencies)
[error] Not a valid project ID: dependency-graph
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: dependency-graph (similar: dependency-classpath, dependencyClasspath, play-dependency-classpath)
[error] dependency-graph

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks.

I tried adding this to my plugins.sbt file:
    addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.4")

and this to my Build.scala:
    net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

but when I enter:
    activator dependency-graph

I get:

    [error] Not a valid command: dependency-graph (similar: dependencies)
    [error] Not a valid project ID: dependency-graph
   ...
    [error] Not a valid key: dependency-graph (similar: dependency-classpath, dependencyClasspath, play-dependency-classpath)
    [error] dependency-graph

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since my attempts to add a comment so far have failed, here is a link to what I've tried and what results, as a pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/92YTECMZ

Comment: I've since figured out the correct syntax in Build.scala to define the sbt-dependency-graph settings.  Still trying to analyze the output to determine what dependencies are forcing 2.10.  Thanks for the pointer to this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be in my Build.scala. While I defined scalaVersion and used it in setting up dependencies, I didn't pass a setting to the Project that overrode the default scalaVersion, which evidently is the one used to build activator (2.10.4). So despite thinking I had set scalaVersion, I hadn't really.